# How do I get a user from a mention in discord.py?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Having an issue with my commands, for some reason this worked last night, but now it only works when I mention my own username when I do it. Am I using the `user=message.mentions[0]` properly?

```python
@client.async_event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    elif message.content.startswith('!punch'):
        user = message.mentions[0]
        responses = ['DANG ' + user.mention + ' just got punched!', 'LOOK OUT ' + user.mention + ' just got knocked out! ლ(ಠ益ಠლ)', 'trong uppercut right in ' + user.mention + 's chin']
        choice = random.choice(responses)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, choice)
```

Comment: What happens if you mention another user?  Are you seeing an error?  Also, the `async_event` decorator isn't necessary if you use the `async def` syntax.  You can use `@client.event` instead.

Comment: Thank you Patrick!

When I mention another user, there's no error thrown and inside of the chat the bot doesn't reply with anything.

Comment: Restarted my comp and it works now. So weird, but I did change to @client.event

Thanks again.